# Clean old Visual Studio solutions that have been upgraded

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I find myself loading old C# solutions from VS2010 which have been upgraded to 2017. Thee appear to be a lot of baggage of folders and files coming along.

Is there a way to clean a solution that removes any unneeded files from old versions and only keeps what is being currently used? There may be old files that aren't even referenced any more in the solutions, but how do I know what is what?.

Comment: I know there's a lot of old nuget crap that doesn't get cleaned up properly, I usually hand edit it.  Potentially the best way to be sure is to recreate the project and add the files / nuget / references

Answer (score 0):

The way to clean is good old elbow grease so to speak. Simply remove a file from the project, or comment out a section of a file you think is not being used any more, rebuild. Put it back if build breaks or refactor it out rinse and repeat.

Of course with code files you can use Visual Studio's built in Find References to help as well.

A tool called Resharper can be used to deep cleaner faster, such as changing namespaces, renaming and finding all implementations but Visual Studio 2017 has all the renaming and reference finding you probably need.

Of course have all the code in source control, and incrementally commit every so often so you can revert a build you might break while removing files and not remember exactly everything you removed.

Comment: Thanks Brian :-) I was hoping for something more automated. Delete and Pray, is going to cause trouble eventually. :-)

Comment: @netchicken I did not suggest praying lol. The approach actually works well and massive projects can be refactored in this fashion, I considered it senior level grunt work. Like I said, Resharper could help you but in the end there is nothing automated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you attempt a conversion, generally Visual Studio creates a Backup directory to prevent the unintentional situations, as converted solutions or projects might be no longer compatible with Visual Studio versions that are earlier than current version of Visual Studio.

In Backup Folder, There should be an old version of your project. 
If it works fine without original version of your project, you may delete whole "Backup" directory as you don't need them anymore.

If any project cannot be converted, it is unloaded and marked as unavailable in Solution Explorer. In this situation, address the problems indicated in the upgrade report as you try to reload the projects that are marked (unavailable), in this case, you may recover from your original project by open a project / solution file located in Backup folder.

Good luck with your project!

[image: [Backup] folder example in an upgraded project directory]